# Click for Date & Click for Time - In specified columns only

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I am a beginner with VBA, and I am wanting assistance to ensure the following codes (which work perfectly) are only applied in a specified column.

**Click for date**
I have a formula which enables you to right click for the current date but I only want it to apply to column D. This is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Target = Date
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

**Click for time** I also have a formula which enables you to double click for real time, again I only want it in two columns, being I & J. This is the code:

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Address = ActiveCell.Address Then
        Target = Format(Now, "ttttt")
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried several codes but to no avail (as I said I am very new to this, so have little experience), any advice or possible code suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the column of the `Target` and then make the entry conditional on it being in the correct column(s).

For your first example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then Target.Value = Date
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Your second example

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
     If Target.Column = 9 Or Target.Column = 10 Then Target.Value = Format(Now, "ttttt")
End Sub
```